# CUDA goes out of memory during inference and gives InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

During inference, when the models are being loaded, Cuda throws InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory.

I am performing inference on a machine with 6GB of VRAM. A few days back, the machine was able to perform the tasks, but now I am frequently getting these messages. Restarting the device sometimes does help, but is not a viable solution. I have checked through nvidia-smi, but it is also showing only about 500 MB of VRam being used and I was not able to see any spike in memory usage when tensorflow was trying to load the models.

I am currently using tensorflow 1.14.0 and python 3.7.4

Comment: Are you training in an IPython Notebook by any chance?

Comment: The problem occurs during inference. And no, jupyter notebooks are not being used for either training or inference.

Comment: Hi Akhil, did you resolve this in the end? I'm getting the same error. Please respond.

Comment: @Qululu I added these 2 lines for clearing previous sessions from memory.
``from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
``

Also, I changed the fraction of the memory used by the model. By default, tf models fill up the entire GPU memory.
You can refer [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1538) for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Tensorflow 2.3.0 on a remote server. My code was working fine, but suddenly the server gets disconnected from the network, and my training stopped. When I re-run the code I got the same issue you got. So I guess this problem is related to GPU being busy in something not existing anymore. Clearing the session as the comment said is enough to solve the problem (I also believe restarting the machine can also fix the problem but I did not get the chance to try this solution).
for tensorflow 2.3 use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` it solve the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: The command is slightly wrong, it should be `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I have fixed this mistake